# What are the uses for the carry flag and the overflow flag in the EFLAGS register?

Tags: assembly, x86

The `EFLAGS` register have a carry flag and an overflow flag, I am wondering what are the uses for these flags.

I can think of the following uses:

- If I am adding two unsigned integers, and I want to know if the
  addition was successful (that is, the the result fitted in the specified register/memory), then I would check if the carry flag is set
  (if it is not set, then the addition was successful).
- If I am adding two signed (two's complement) numbers, and I want to
  know if the addition was successful (that is, the the result fitted in the specified register/memory without overflowing the sign bit), then I would check if the
  overflow flag is set (if it is not set, then the addition was
  successful).

Are these uses correct? and are there any other uses?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overflow_flag

Comment: The usage of carry flag is quite well discussed in the duplicate article, however, the other part is not. I haven't seen any tricks using OF but would be interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flags are the only ways to control condition instructions which are, conditional jumps (`jCC`) and conditional moves (`cmovCC` and `fcmovCC`). Thus, whenever you want to make a choice depending on some condition like

- are two numbers equal?
- is one number larger than the other?
- is a number zero?
- is a certain bit set in a number?
- is the number's parity even or odd?

You need the flags register. For this purpose, the `cmp` instruction exists. It subtracts its operands, discards the result and sets the flags. This way, you can compare numbers and do something according to the result. See [this table](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_146.html) for how the order of two numbers affects the flags.

Lastly, you can also use the flags (especially the carry flag) to do large number addition. This is facilitated using the `adc` and `sbb` instructions which carry over the carry or borrow from lesser digits to higher digits.

Comment: What about the uses I gave in my question, are they correct?

Comment: Yes but they aren't super common.

Comment: @joseph_m usually you resolve any data type overflow by the design of code and sanitizing the input values, so in the middle of computation you don't check the carry/overflow any more, because you are sure the result will either fit, or your design is expected to overflow and handle that appropriately. Checking it dynamically after every arithmetic may be valid in special scenarios (doing dynamic "calculator" like evaluation of user expression, tossing out "error" in case of overflow), but most of the SW is designed to run it's main calculation without checks (it's much faster).